# How to Stop Web Page Reloading?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to work around with a Code which will fetch data without browser page reloading. Yes, I know, AJAX is the solution. But let me first show you the codes :

**AJAX Part :**

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                <!-- for sumitting the form -->
                function tabSubmit(obj,e){
                var e=(typeof event!='undefined')?window.event:e;// IE : Moz
                if(e.keyCode==13){
                        if(document.getElementById("rollno").value == ''){
                        alert("Please Enter Roll No");
                        document.getElementById("rollno").focus();
                        return false;
                        }else{
                            var rollno = document.getElementById("rollno").value;                   
                            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                                //if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {              
                                    document.getElementById("pt_marks_initial").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                    document.getElementById("pt_marks_initial").focus();
                                }
                            };
                            xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php?rollno=" + rollno, true);
                            xmlhttp.send();
                        }
                    }
                }
                </script>
```

**HTML Parts :**

```
                <form name="search" id="search" method="post">
                <label for="rollno">Roll No:</label>
                 <input name="rollno" id="rollno" maxlength="14" size="30" onKeyPress='return tabSubmit(this,event)' />
                </form>


                <form name='receiveform' id='receiveform' method='post'>                
                <label for='rollno'>Roll No</label> <input type='text' name='srollno' id='srollno' value='' readonly='readonly' />
                <label for='pt_marks_initial'>PT MARKS INITIAL</label> <input type='text' name='pt_marks_initial' id='pt_marks_initial' value='' />
                </form>
```

The problem is that the the focus is not remaining set to the desired form element because the page is being reloaded after AJAX Call. Also if I use the two conditions as mentioned in the code below :

```
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
```

then it is also not entering into the if block. I am not being able to find out the bug. Please help.

Comment: is the address you're calling returning a redirect by any chance?

Comment: @Jakumi ajax doesn't follow redirect headers by default so that won't be it. (After all, if it did, that would kinda defeat the point of ajax - i.e. no refreshes/postbacks/redirects)

Comment: Samcoder I think you need to return false from your tabSubmit function to stop the default postback action happening simultaneously to your ajax call. Can you try that please?

Comment: @ADyson. I have tested adding return false just before the last brace but did not work. Can you please suggest the appropriate location to insert the return statement?

Comment: @ADyson. Sorry for my last comment. It worked. Thanks